# 2D array diagonal checking for "X"

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I tried to create a 2D array and place four "X" in diagonal and created a double loop for detecting and counting the number of Xs but instead of displaying just one "player 1 won" it displays 10 of them.

```
var creatematrix = function (nbRang, nbColumn) {
    var result = Array(nbRang);
    for (var i=0; i<nbRang; i++) {
        result[i] = Array(nbColumn);
    }
    return result;
};

var m = creatematrix(6, 7);

m[4][1] = "X";
m[3][2] = "X";
m[2][3] = "X";
m[1][4] = "X";



var sumX = 0;
for(var k = 5; k >= 0  ; k--){
    for(var i = 0 ; i<= 6; i++){
        if(m[k][i]== "X" ){
            sumX += 1;
        }
        else if(sumX == 4){
            alert("player 1 won");      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: add a `break` statement after - `alert("player 1 won");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the question is how to make the code to show the alert only once - you should set a flag for which user has one and when the game has ended, then use the alert in the end.

Now the alert is in the loop, so it will be fired every time the loop does.

Answer (score 0):

Your total loop executes 42 times (6x7). Apparently, in the 32nd iteration, `sumX` reaches value 4. Hence, all 10 times after that, the `alert` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Once you detect a winner, you aren't stopping your loop.

You might try one of these options:

1. Add a condition to both your `for` loop checks to see if you've already got `sumX == 4`
2. `return` from function after alert